# Google follows redirect and ignores if construct?

Tags: php, redirect, google-plus

in my site i have a redirect via header("location") which only will be executed when the user logged in not exists, redirecting to the login form. I have a google+ button on this site and google always follows the redirect. I cannot get it why?

When i remove this redirect everything is fine. I tried with this code:

```
if (!$user->user_exists && !getIsCrawler($userAgent)) {
header("Location: login.php"); }
```

To detect the crawler i use this function:

```
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
function getIsCrawler($userAgent) { 
$crawlers = 'Google|msnbot|Rambler|Yahoo|AbachoBOT|accoona|' . 'AcioRobot|ASPSeek|CocoCrawler|Dumbot|FAST-WebCrawler|'
 .'GeonaBot|Gigabot|Lycos|MSRBOT|Scooter|AltaVista|IDBot|eStyle|Scrubby'; $isCrawler =
 (preg_match("/$crawlers/", $userAgent) > 0); return $isCrawler; }
```

What am i doing wrong here? I hope that someone of you have a solution for this.

Comment: really no one an idea how i can manage this? I do not understand why google ignores the if construct. Maybe there is alternative way to redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to get around this problem. Google is known to be using different user agents (with obscure names) in order to check for web pages that show different content to search engines and regular users, or the so called cloaking/doorway pages.

Comment: so the only way to solve this, is instead of redirecting when user is not logged in, maybe include a login form directly. I thoght of it, but i am not happy with such a solution. Hm thought there is a way to tell google to ignore that part of code. Nevermind then i will do it without the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

User agents can be easily spoofed. So you might want to be careful with that portion of your code and consider reevaluating it.

You should check out Gus Class' article on how to to render the necessary markup when you need to put content behind a paywall or log in: http://gusclass.com/blog/2012/08/15/rendering-schema-org-markup-for-content-behind-a-paywall/

Basically putting passing the necessary data to your log in page could allow the crawlers to still retrieve the metadata that they need while protecting your site with the log in.